# cPickle - unpickling error ONLY when the unpickled stuff is used later on

Tags: python, pickle

The code I write now works fine, I can even print the deserialized objects with no mistakes whatsoever, so I do know exactly what is in there.

```
@staticmethod
def receiveData(self):
    '''
    This method has to be static, as it is the argument of a Thread.
    It receives Wrapperobjects from the server (as yet containing only a player)
    and resets the local positions accordingly
    '''

    logging.getLogger(__name__).info("Serverinformationen werden nun empfangen")
    from modules.logic import game
    sock = self.sock
    time.sleep(10)
    self.myPlayer = game.get_player()
    while (True):
        try:
            wrapPacked = sock.recv(4096)
            self.myList = cPickle.loads(wrapPacked)
         #   self.setData(self.myList)             
        except Exception as eload:            
            print eload
```

However, if I try to actually use the line that is in comments here (self.setData(self.myList),

I get

```
unpickling stack underflow
```

and

```
invalid load key, ' '.
```

Just for the record, the  code of setData is:

```
def setData(self, list):    
    if (list.__sizeof__()>0):
        first = list [0]
        self.myPlayer.setPos(first[1])
        self.myPlayer.setVelocity(first[2])
```

I have been on this for 3 days now, and really, I have no idea what is wrong.
Can you help me?
Full Traceback:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "mypath/client.py", line 129, in receiveData
    self.myList = cPickle.loads(wrapPacked)
UnpicklingError: unpickling stack underflow –
```

Comment: Can you give us the *full* tracebacks?

Comment: after removing the try catch, yes, but there is hardly more information:

Comment: Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "mypath/client.py", line 129, in receiveData
    self.myList = cPickle.loads(wrapPacked)
UnpicklingError: unpickling stack underflow

Comment: You should [edit] your question with that info. And threading? Have you considered the possibility that you created a race condition?

Comment: Does the problem go away when you switch to the pure-python `pickle` module?

Comment: I did consider that, but I am not using different threads where it comes in. setData is in the same thread as the unpickling. so, when the unpickling has worked without setData, setData should not cause an unpickling error?

Comment: I switched to cPickle to avoid other such problems in the first place.

Comment: If it helps, I can PRINT my unpickled Data just fine in setData as well, that is:

Comment: print (first) works absolutely fine, but print first; self.myPlayer.setPos(first[0]) leads to an exception. Is that actually possible?

Comment: No, that is not normally possible; it is theoretically possible that the cPickle module didn't handle a c-level exception and that exception is shown later on. Have you verified that your pickle file can actually be loaded properly in a non-threaded program?

Comment: It is not a pickle file that I am using - hence the use of dumps and loads instead of dump and load. And as I said,  my Data CAN be deserialized, that is loaded, just fine: If I first deserialize and then load them, I geht exactly the values I expect - only when I try to do sth. more then printing with thoes values does the pickle exception occur.

Comment: That's the part that makes no sense; dump the data, try and load it separately. And if there is a bug in the C code that doesn't handle an exception properly somewhere then the *next* problem will show the previously I unhandled exception instead.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, what is it you say I should do? (sry, I am no native in english)

Comment: Save the `wrapPacked` variable contents to a file. Start a new interpreter, load `cPickle` and load the file contents, then try to `loads()` the data again and see what happens.

Comment: good idea....I do that tomorrow though - it is 1 a m here. listen, can you not write that into an answer so that I can...how do you call it...value that?

Comment: FYI: use `if list` to check if a list is non-empty. Never use `__sizeof__`; it returns the in-memory size of an object which is implementation-dependent. If you want the number of elements, use `len(list)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that your exceptions always happen when you try to access the pickled data seem to indicate that you are hitting a bug in the `cPickle` library instead.

What can happen is that a C library forgets to handle an exception. The exception info is stored, not handled, and is sitting there in the interpreter until *another* exception happens or another piece of C code *does* check for an exception. At this point the old, unhandled exception is thrown instead.

Your error is clearly `cPickle` related, it is very unhappy about the data you feed it, but the exception itself is thrown in unrelated locations. This *could* be threading related, it could be a regular non-threading-related bug.

You need to see if you can load the data in a test setting. Write `wrapPacked` to a file for later testing. Load that file in a interpreter shell session, load it with `cPickle.loads()` and see what happens. Do the same with the `pickle` module.

If you do run into similar problems in this test session, and you can reproduce it (weird exceptions being thrown at a later point in the session) you need to file a bug with the Python project to have this looked at.

Comment: I just did that (thanks for the hint). The problem is, I cannot reproduce the bug. What I did is: I ran my programm you see above and added a few lines which wrote the contents of wrapPacked to a file file.txt. I then went and wrote a script which has nothing to do with the actual project which consists of five lines or so (including imports). All it does: f = open ("file.txt", "r"), str = f.read(), print (cPickle.loads(str)). The Problem is: I got the values I wanted and NO ERRORS AT ALL. Had there been an exception or even rubbish prints you would clearly been right but this?

Comment: Then it appears to be thread-related; did you write just any pickle to the file or one that triggers the error? If the latter, and the data reads fine, then try to provoke the error *with* threading (set up several threads, try to unpickle in one or multiple). If the former, only write the file if an exception was raised. If that pickle doesn't load, check for threading problems with reading from the socket.

Comment: I guess it must be threading problems....it is the only thing that would make sense. and of course the pickle from the exception would not load, I tried that already. I just do not see how I could possibly have threading problems here: you see, the data are dumped/send and received/loaded not just in different threads but in different processes. How can they POSSIBLY interact? I thougt the whole idea about processes is that there is no way whatsoever that they interact (except I force it on purpose)

Comment: Due to other issues I did think for a while that the two processes would interact - only I thought until now this is a physical impossibility? is not it?

Comment: Another option: did you test if you received *enough* data? Just because you ask for 4096 bytes doesn't mean you've received that many. How do you know you have a _complete_ pickle there?

Comment: I do not know how many bytes I have though I can check. However, I asked for a list of tuples with Numbers in it, which is exactly what I am getting. So yes, I actually do get all the data I want.

Comment: Can we put this to chat? I do not want to be banned for this discussion.

Comment: You won't be banned for using too many comments on your post :-) Chat would have to wait until tomorrow, it very late here in CET...

Comment: fair enough....I banned that problem though. You were right, it IS mainly a threading problem - one thread blocking the other. I just do not seem to realize why but I fear that is too deep into the project for a topic.

Comment: Do you think I may open a topic to the threading problem here, having identified the two threads that block each other#

Comment: Sure, open a new question.